# NodeJs callback and parameters

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I came across this piece of code which needs some clarification.
[http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html#:~:text=The%20next%20%28%29%20function%20is%20not%20a%20part,%E2%80%9Cnext%E2%80%9D.%20To%20avoid%20confusion%2C%20always%20use%20this%20convention](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html#:%7E:text=The%20next%20%28%29%20function%20is%20not%20a%20part,%E2%80%9Cnext%E2%80%9D.%20To%20avoid%20confusion%2C%20always%20use%20this%20convention).
Refer section : **"Configurable middleware"**

How is it possible that "req", "res" and "next" can be referred inside the exported function directly ? I mean neither the caller "app.use()" nor the CB export definition "module.exports" = function(options){   }" are having any references to them.

----- block using an exported middleware ----

```
const mw = require('./my-middleware.js');    
app.use(mw({ option1: '1', option2: '2' }))
```

}

------  Exported Function --------

```
module.exports = function (options) {

  // Please explain the below access/visibility of req, res and next parameters.
  // I do not see them passed/referred/handed-down from app.use() level.
  return function (req, res, next) {
    // Implement the middleware function based on the options object
    next()
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every express middleware function has access to `request`, `response`, and a callback function, conventionally named as `next`.

How does a middleware have access to these?
When you register a function as a middleware, express passes that middleware function the above mentioned parameters as arguments.

So, when you create a function with the intention of it being used as a middleware, you already know that it will receive three arguments from express. As a result, you create a function with the 3 parameters mentioned above:

```
function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  ...
}
```

Sometimes, we want the middleware function to be configurable; so we create a function that takes some configuration options and then return a function that will be used as a middleware function.

And as we know that each middleware function will be passed 3 arguments by express, we define the inner function to take 3 parameters:

```
function returnConfigurableMiddleware(options) {
   ...
   return (req, res, next) => {
      ...
   }
}
```

In this case, to register the middleware, we have to *call* the function that returns the function to be used as a middleware.

```
app.use(returnConfigurableMiddleware(...))
```

Comment: "then return a function that will be used as a middleware function.".......I now see that we are returning a whole middleware function definition, and since any middleware function automatically has access to these 3 parameters, we are defining the returned function accordingly to handle these 3 params.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think this way: The Exported Function defines a function which accepts (req, res, next) as parameter.

Normally When you define a function there are no restrictions on how you define the parameters.

But, in this case, the parameters has to be (req, res, next) because you are defining a express middleware

Answer (score 0):

> neither the caller [...] nor the CB export definition [...] are having any references to them

That's because nothing in the code shown is ever calling that function.  You're exporting a function that *returns a function*.  The *outer* function is being called here:

```
mw({ option1: '1', option2: '2' })
```

That returns a function, but doesn't *call* that function.  It just passes it as the only parameter to `app.use()`.

Based on the usage, presumably `app` is an [Express object](https://expressjs.com/), and it's `.use()` function is [how you build middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) for the Express web server.

So, internal to the workings of Express, as part of the HTTP request/response pipeline, *it* will call your `function (req, res, next)` at some later time.  And when it does, *it* will pass (at least) three arguments to that function.